# Retry a HTTP request in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection to send an HTTP request and running it with
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
where "request" is a configured NSMutableURLRequest object. Upon an HTTP error based on error code (404 or 500), I want to retry the request.

I get the error response and HTTP status code in the "connection: didReceiveResponse" delegate methods. How should I implement the retry request?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I tried canceling the connection and starting it on receiving an error but it has no effect as NSURLConnection releases the delegate after it finishes loading or is cancelled.

-----UPDATE-----

```
    -(void)doHTTPGet:(NSString *)url delegate:(id  <NSURLConnectionDelegate>)delegate timeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:timeout];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // send request by instanciating NSURLConnection
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];

}
```

In my model class, I have the caller method and delegates

Caller:

```
[MyModel doHTTPGet:url delegate:self timeout:HTTP_TIMEOUT];
```

Delegate Methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    httpResponseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    DLOG(@"HTTP status code=%ld", (long)httpResponseStatusCode);

    if (httpResponseStatusCode == 404)
    {
       // RETRY HERE
    } 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [httpResponseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    // some code PROCESSING RESPONSE
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrap the `NSURLConnection` functionality stuff inside another class (in my case, called APIGetter), which has its own delegate protocol and methods and handles things like retrying.

If you don't want to do that, then you'll need to save the parameters and URL, and try again, perhaps in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

Though, I'm trying to imagine a scenario where you'd want to retry on a `4xx` HTTP error. Seems more likely on a connection error, so you'd put it in `connection:didFailWithError`.

Comment: I did initially try this in connectionDidFinishLoading    if(httpResponseStatusCode == 404)
    {
        [MyModel doGet:[connection currentRequest].URL delegate:self timeout:HTTP_TIMEOUT ];
    }

Comment: But since the retried request is asynchronous, by the time I get the response, the next part of the code is getting executed..

Comment: By the time you get the response? You should make a call back to your other code only when you're ready.

Comment: I actually want to retry on a 500 error, and the delegate method - connection:didFailWithError is not triggered on 4XX or 5XX errors

Comment: Yes, got it. My bad, I had an incorrect condition in there due to which the next callback code was triggering without waiting for the HTTP operation. I got it working fine now.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Inside your response just use a switch or if statement to check for the errors you wish and if your response is 404 or 500 reload the request

This is pseudo code:

if error contains string(404 or 500) {

//call the function which loads the request

}

Comment: I did initially try this in connectionDidFinishLoading    if(httpResponseStatusCode == 404)
    {
        [MyModel doGet:[connection currentRequest].URL delegate:self timeout:HTTP_TIMEOUT ];
    }

Comment: But since the retried request is asynchronous, by the time I get the response, the next part of the code is getting executed..

Comment: did you try //Capturing server response
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: I need to retry using an Async request as I need to process the response. I cannot send a synchronous request

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [STNetTaskQueue](https://github.com/kevin0571/STNetTaskQueue) for you as it provides retry time and retry interval for each net task.

What's more, it can pack request parameters from a request object automatically, and max concurrent net task is also configurable.